# Flutter: App Get Stuck on Emulator at Loading Circle

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to make an app to read data from Cloud Firestore (Firebase)

I made a collection called "shopping_list" on Firebase and added a string document

But when I try to read it from my app, it gets stuck at loading screen (on main page) and stays there. I can log in or log out but can not view my data.

[emulator photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBJYY.png)

Here is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:naturaperion_v3/login_page.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';


void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
  );

  FlutterError.onError=FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            {
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            }
          if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active)
          {
            if(snapshot.data==null)
              {
                return LoginPage();
              }
            else
              {
                return MyHomePage(title: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName!);
              }
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      )
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  CollectionReference _referenceShoppingList= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('shopping_list');
  late Stream <QuerySnapshot> _streamShoppingItems;


  initState(){
    super.initState();

    _streamShoppingItems=_referenceShoppingList.snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () async{
            await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
            FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

    }, icon: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new))
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _streamShoppingItems,
        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){

          if(snapshot.hasError)
          {
            return Center (child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
          }

          if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active)
          {
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot=snapshot.data;
          }

          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried changing code, recreating the document and collection as well as waiting for hours but it did not help.

Comment: try debugging/printing `snapshot`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh did not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to return some widget, else it will ge the last return >

Try to follow this pattern

```dart
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _streamShoppingItems,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
      }
      // this condtion was missing return statement, that's why last one[ProgressIndicator] was showing all the time
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) { /// prefer done over active
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: querySnapshot.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[index];
            return Text("got data");
            // return ListTile(
            //   title: Text(documentSnapshot['name']),
            //   subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot['price'].toString()),
            // );
          },
        );
      }

      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  ),
```

Comment: nothing changed. no text or sth. does this mean I have problem with connection?

Comment: do you still get `CircularProgressIndicator`? if not, then yes could be connection issue

Comment: yes I get it. It still loops forever

Comment: do you mean it is still showing the `CircularProgressIndicator` forever?  ok, try adding ` ConnectionState.active`

Comment: Glad to help, You can find more about [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)